# По крайней мере

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли здесь запятые?

*Качество сериала по крайней мере на протяжении первых четырёх сезонов было безупречным*.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь  "по крайней мере" **не является вводным  сочетанием и не обособляется**, это обстоятельство со значением оценки "самое меньшее", "не меньше чем", однако структура данного предложения неудобна для чтения, ее желательно как-то изменить.

(1) Вариант с обособлением (весь распространенный оборот в позиции между подлежащим и сказуемым может быть обособлен, тогда  "по крайней мере" будет выступать в функции присоединительного союза): **Качество сериала,  по крайней мере на протяжении первых четырёх сезонов,  было безупречным.**

(2) Другой вариант (при изменении позиции): **По крайней мере на протяжении пЕрвых четырёх сезонов // качество сериала  было безупречным.** Здесь структура и интонация простого предложения (обозначено логическое ударение, а также  пауза между двумя частями предложения)

Comment: Если отвечать конкретно на вопрос топикстартера -- то вариант, отмеченный как `(1)`. Вариант `(2)` правильный, но тогда уж для полноты картины надо привести и вариант `(3)` **Качество сериала было безупречным -- по крайней мере, на протяжении первых четырёх сезонов.** (не уверен, что знаки правильно расставил)